# Issue PDO SET MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, set

I am getting error when try to execute the following query! I keep getting a "general error" and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

TRY 1:

```
$conn = pdoClass::getConnection();

$sql = "set @total := 0;
        SELECT bank_guarantee_id, 
        @total := amount + @total AS TOTAL,
        @total % 800 AS REMAINDER
            FROM bank_guarantee
            WHERE @total < 800;";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$companyname = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in 


 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in
```

TRY 2:

```
try{
    $sql = "set @total := 0;";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
try{
    $sql = "SELECT bank_guarantee_id, @total := amount + @total AS TOTAL, @total-800 AS REMAINDER
    FROM bank_guarantee
    WHERE @total < 800;";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $companyname = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
)
```

Any input would be appreciate!!

SQL FIDDLE LINK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea0ea/1

Comment: put your connection code in to exception handling and check for out put of catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}

Comment: it says Exeption: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error @HarshalMahajan

Comment: Try with prepare & execute statement

Comment: I tried but it returns empty array...

Comment: and the error is gone while using them ?

Comment: yes :( @HarshalMahajan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44321/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-tomphp)

Comment: That would be 2 statements. Run the `SET` & `SELECT` as 2 seperate queries & everything will be fine & dandy.

Comment: did that but no use empty array comes as an output..

Comment: @Wrikken i have updated the code kindly check the question..

Comment: What is the result you're hoping ?

Comment: @dagfr check my fiddle link..

Comment: I looked at it, but I don't understand what the result your are hoping to have. Why total<800 ? You want the total of all bank or the total per bank ?

Comment: It a process.. you can see the result comming up.. that i am not able to fetch using PDO..